# WP8.1 Opaque hidden AppBar/CommandBar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How do I achieve opaque CommandBar/AppBar while it's hidden in WP8.1? CommandBar's property Opacity works just fine, but only when AppBar is opened. Though even then you can see non-opaque rectangle at the bottom. I want my AppBar to be opaque at all times, even when ClosedDisplayMode is set to Minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED] 
"This happens because when you create a CommandBar an automatic margin is created for the ContentGrid to free a space below it for the app bar. Give the Main Grid a bottom margin by -24 and your content will show behind the command bar Like this: Margin="0,0,0,-24"

[ORIGINAL COMMENT]
I guess it is not applicable to do it with the control itself. But the workaround is to give it an opaque color. You can give the command bar a color but reduce its alpha value that controls the color's transparency.

Example: that's the Color code of the "Red" color with 80% transparency: #CCFF0000

Comment: That's clever. But sadly, there still is a solid red bar at the very bottom of AppBar.

Comment: This bar won't appear if you're setting the background brush of the page in the Page control not in the Grid inside it.

Comment: I am setting background brush of the page in Page control. In the Grid there's only Pivot control and that's it.
I'm running Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime App, BTW.

Comment: I've tested it on a WP8.1 App and works fine. Could you share with me that piece of XAML code?

Comment: There you go: http://pastebin.com/Y0UzvQbT .
Oryginally it's much longer, but I've removed parts that seemed irrelevant and left the bare bones.

Comment: You're right, What is appearing is a Bar with 80% transparency Red color because its color code is Red with 80 alpha value. If you want it fully transparent just make it: #00FF0000

Comment: That is not what I'm aiming for. Take a look at this: http://imgur.com/ADXhyV9 . I want solid red bar to be opaque as well.

Comment: not sure when you want it to be opaque and when you want it to be solid color. Do you want it to be solid when it's closed then when it's opened it turns to be transparent?

Comment: To quote myself, from original question: I want my AppBar to be opaque at all times, even when ClosedDisplayMode is set to Minimal.

In other words - what is solid red in the picture I posted must be opaque as well.

Comment: Changing the Alpha value as I've said in my answer works with me. Try reducing to less than 80% for example 60% : #99FF0000. Also, if you're testing only on the emulator try to test it on a device.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure we understand each other. I want my AppBar to be 90% opaque at all times. Even when it's hidden, I want to see content underneath it.
Is this how it looks for you? May I see a screenshot?

Comment: Oh Yes I got it now. This happens because when you create a CommandBar an automatic margin is created for the ContentGrid to free a space below it for the app bar. Give the Main Grid a bottom margin by -24 and your content will show behind the command bar
Like this:     <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-24" >

Comment: Thank you very much, setting Grid margin is just what I needed. BTW, setting Background color with opacity is not necessary, Opacity property works just fine.

Comment: Please add the abouv comment to main answer for quick resolution. worked for me. thanks